# How to get specific values of items from other sheets based on column names in the master sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, vlookup, textjoin

To describe my problem here is my sheet

[Master sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK93u.png)

Here, From Column E onwards there are different attributes for each of the items in column A.

Now, I have a subsheet based on the type of the items as listed in column B, here

[Subsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9ltJ.png)

Here we can see from Column C onwards attributes of the items in column A. In this case, the other attributes from the master sheet above that are not mentioned do not apply to these items and therefore will be blank in the master sheet.

My problem is to populate the attributes of the corresponding items from the subsheet that are in column C to F, in the master sheet where all the attributes are listed. I only want to add those values that exist in the sub sheet and leave the rest blank.

Here is a sample sheet with the desired output. There is a Master sheet and an Subsheet named DEF. The Master sheet has to lookup the values from the Subsheet and filled the appropriate cells based on the reference from column A and B of the Master sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lNPPhTr7_N0N8CA7BLyO9JhYGd1Hx0c6Q0Uq4Wdt_GY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I've added a sample of my sheet in the post player0, I was thinking of using a nested Index Function to first lookup the the name of the item and match it with the subsheet and then another to check the name of column and match with what is in the master sheet among the various column names and fill the values accordingly. However, I'm still working out the exact formula, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in D2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {DEF!A:A&DEF!B:B, DEF!C:Z}, 
 IFERROR(MATCH(D1:P1, DEF!A1:Z1, 0)-1, 100), 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, this works. I have a question though How can modify it so that I could also include other sub sheets based on the other types. I tried to add the range from the other sheets in the vlookup but it didn't work. Should I use Index instead of Vlookup here to do that?